# Can we call 2 times response.redirect to open different page with different url?

Tags: c#, response.redirect

i am developing c# program and about to display 2 reports (crystal report) in 2 tabs. for this i tried response.redirect, but it only works for the first response.redirect. it is not going to the second response.redirect...does anyone know how to work around this issue? here goes my codes:

```
                    if (Request.QueryString["ProcessName"].ToString().Equals("MyBill"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyBill", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = Request.QueryString["id"];

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@billamount", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters["@billamount"].Value = Request.QueryString["billamount"];

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_displaydocno", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_billno_out", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //Print Bill
                        string ReportName = "Bill_New.rpt";
                        string billid = null;

                        string piping = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@p_billno_out"].Value);
                        string audit_no = string.Empty;

                        string[] strArr = null;
                        char[] splitchar = { '|' };
                        strArr = piping.Split(splitchar);
                        audit_no = strArr[0].Trim();
                        billid = strArr[1].Trim();
                        auditno = Convert.ToInt32(audit_no);

                        string URL = "./Reports/Reports.aspx?ReportName=" + ReportName +  "&billid=" + billid;
                        Response.Redirect(URL);

                        //Print Receipt
                        string ReportName2 = "Receipt.rpt";
                        string DocNoFrom = null;
                        string DocNoTo = null;

                        DocNoFrom = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@p_displaydocno"].Value);
                        DocNoTo = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@p_displaydocno"].Value);

                        string URL2 = "./Reports/Reports.aspx?ReportName=" + ReportName2 + "&DocNoFrom=" + DocNoFrom + "&DocNoTo=" + DocNoTo;
                        Response.Redirect(URL2);

                        Cursor.Current = Cursors.AppStarting;
                    }

                    con.Close();
                }
```

Edited: then i tried javascript to replace response.redirect, yes it opens 2 tabs but got this error

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open(URL, '_blank');</script>");
Response.Write("<script>window.open(URL2, '_blank');</script>");
```

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUL9C.png)
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4BL9.png)

Comment: You can not do more than one Response.Redirect in single flow. You can use JavaScript code to open two different URLs using window.open one after another. And create crystal reports on those urls

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya do u hv any sample to add crystal report in javascript? i hv created using javascript and calling the url, but got error

Comment: Are you defining the javascript variables "URL" and "URL2"?

Comment: i get the value from the variable URL and URL2 above. string URL = "./Reports/Reports.aspx?ReportName=" + ReportName +  "&billid=" + billid;

Comment: Those are C# variables, they have no way of getting into javascript. You either need to build the script you write to the page, or write them as javascript variables.

Comment: ok will try to write as js variable